# Light passes through walls

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, 3d-modelling

I've just build few models in MagicsVoxel editor and imported them into unity 2019.3.10f1.
But when adding any light (Point, Object with emissive materials) to one of the room, saw that liht passes through walls.

Help please, tried many different solutions.

Thanks.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the emmision is in the walls. What i mena by that is that you have an emission shape of the light source it looks like a hitbox and i think you have that going trough the walls, and that may be the reason it passes trough them

Comment: I've tried many different positions for the light sources even made additional primitives to block the light

Answer (score 0):

Just select the light, and set shadow type to 'hard shadows' or 'soft shadows'
Be sure shadows are enabled from quality settings